Kubernetes Cronjob execution on specific node
I’m working on a setup where I need to run a specific container via a Kubernetes CronJob on a specific node. The workflow involves:
1️⃣ Launching a new node just before the CronJob execution.
2️⃣ Running the container on the new node.
3️⃣ Terminating the node after the container completes.
Here’s my current approach:

First CronJob (10:00 AM): Scales up the ASG to launch a new node using the AWS CLI.

Second CronJob (10:05 AM): Runs the container on the new node and scales down the ASG after completion.


The setup includes:

Node selection via nodeSelector.
Scaling logic using AWS CLI commands in the containers.

Here's a snippet from the configuration for context:
First CronJob (Scale Up):
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: scale-up-asg-job
spec:
  schedule: "0 10 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: scale-up-asg
              image: amazon/aws-cli:latest
              command:
                - sh
                - -c
                - |
                  aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "AutoScalingGroups[*].AutoScalingGroupName" --output text
                  echo "Scaling up the ASG to 1 instance..."
                  aws autoscaling set-desired-capacity --auto-scaling-group-name "eks-java-appp-XXXXXXXXX" --desired-capacity 1 --region us-east-1
          restartPolicy: Never

Second CronJob (Main Task & Scale Down):
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: schedule-ec2-task-sample-application
spec:
  schedule: "5 10 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: atp
        spec:
          restartPolicy: Never
          initContainers: # Scale up the ASG before starting the job
            - name: sample-java-db-app # Main application container
              image: 637423423652.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/java-db-app
              command:
                - sh
                - -c
                - |
                  echo "Running the main application..."
                  # Add your application's logic here
                  sleep 120 # Simulating application runtime
                  echo "Main application finished."
          containers:
            - name: scale-down-asg # Sidecar to scale down the ASG after job completion
              image: amazon/aws-cli:latest
              command:
                - sh
                - -c
                - |
                  aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "AutoScalingGroups[*].AutoScalingGroupName" --output text
                  echo "Scaling up the ASG to 1 instance..."
                  aws autoscaling set-desired-capacity --auto-scaling-group-name "eks-atp-test-76c9cabf-3ae0-ea1b-052b-9ab155498992" --desired-capacity 0 --region us-east-1
          nodeSelector:
            app: java-db-node # Ensure the job runs on the correct node

Does this approach seem efficient? Is there a better way to handle this kind of workload?

Also is it the right approach to run main task container as initContainer, as it is serving my purpose, because after completion of task, termination of node container is launched so they both are running sequentially

There's a dedicated [devops.se] and it's more likely you'll find DevOps people there.  IME you rarely want to schedule things on specific nodes or create a node just to run one container; instead, just create the CronJob normally and have it create its Pod as needed, and configure the cluster autoscaler if you need more capacity to run it.

A better solution is to use Karpenter to automatically create the new machine for the job. Since the node selector java-db-node exists that means the pod won't schedule on any node without this selector. So if you were to create a node pool with this specific label then the number of machines will remain at 0 until the job starts. When the job starts, the pod will remain in a pending state until Karpenter schedules the machines. Once the job is finished, Karpenter will remove the machine. This way you won't need to create a second cronjob.
We use Karpenter instead of cluster autoscaler because CA can't scale to zero and there will need to be one machine with label "java-db-node" running at all times which might defeat the purpose.
Of course this solution might be too complicated since you already have a tech stack running on your cluster and using Karpenter may not be feasible. In this case the option with the second CronJob is perfectly fine.
